# Boot Windows 8 with Modern UI and a desktop application, in split screen view, feasible?

Tags: windows-8.1, boot, modern-ui

The way I expect this to work is as follows:

1. Windows 8 starts and executes code, scripts or configurations...
2. The Desktop application is launched and goes full screen
3. The RT application is launched (in the background perhaps)
4. The screen is split in two showing both applications :

[image]

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: This is only possible if you have two monitors.